# MS Access - Selecting an ID by selecting the linked name in a form

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, relational-database

### The problem

I've currently been altering my MS Access database to be centred around Client ID rather than Client Name.  However all my forms are still based on Client Name.  I need to change this to be based on Client ID, but I want it to still appear as just Client Name to the users.

### The structure

Before I go any further, I should explain the two relevant tables:

ClientTable:

- ClientID (PK)

- ClientName (indexed, no duplicates)

EntityTable:

- EntityName (CK, no duplicates)

- ClientID (CK, duplicates allowed)

- ClientName (a remnant of my past structure, I figure I won't need this once I've sorted this issue out)

Key relationship: One Client has many Entities

There's also good reason for my composite key (CK) but I won't go into explaining that - my whole structure is far more complicated than shown above.

### The form

So back to the form.  Currently I have an 'Entity' form, which includes an EntityName text box and a ClientName dropdown box.

What I want to happen is that the Client Name dropdown box is visually and functionally the same for the user (i.e. when making a new entity, the user selects a client name), but what needs to happen is that it's actually selecting the Client ID and associating it to that record.

I figure this is a fairly common problem but haven't found an solution in my browsing.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can simply be solved by changing the Row Source to:

```
SELECT ClientID, ClientName & SomeIdentifierForDups FROM ClientTable
```

Changing ...

```
Control source : ClientID  
Column count   : 2
Column widths  : 0; 2
```

Where ClientID referes to the bound table for the form.

Comment: Hi Remou, thanks for your reply.  However I'm having trouble implementing this.  1) In the Data tab in the Property Sheet for that combo box, I've changed the Control Source to "ClientID  (Bound table for form)".  I'm getting an error notification on the combobox saying there needs to be an equal sign in front. 2) I changed the Row Source to "SELECT ClientID, ClientName & SomeIdentifierForDups FROM ClientTable" and it's prompting for SomeIdentifierForDups - should I be changing this to something? 3) Can't see anything called "Column count" or "Column widths" - am I looking in the right place?

Comment: When I tried it out, all I saw was a list of "ClientID".  However the number of rows matches the number of rows in the client list, so at least that much is working.

Comment: Nevermind I've managed to get it working.  Here's my changes: 1) Control source: "ClientID" 2) Row Source: "SELECT ClientTable.[ClientName], ClientTable.[ClientID] FROM ClientTable;" 3) Bound Column: "2". This all seems to be working fine, though I admint I'm a bit nervous - changing the primary key on the main table is not a light matter! I'll just need to do checks on it all. Thanks for the help!